# WebDriverException: Message: ERROR The test with session id new_request:2276271 has already finished, and can't receive further commands

Tags: python, appium, saucelabs

We're running parallel tests in Saucelabs but we keep encountering this issue. This happens almost always now and is giving our workflow a flaky run.

`HOOK-ERROR in before_scenario: WebDriverException: Message: ERROR The test with session id new_request:2276271 has already finished, and can't receive further commands.`

The session stops at this point (creating a session) and not proceeding to assign `imiplicit_wait` on the next step
[image]

Here is our sample `environment.py`.

```
import os
import time
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.common import InvalidSessionIdException
from app.application import Application


def before_scenario(context, scenario):

    sauce_username = os.environ["SAUCE_USERNAME"]
    sauce_access_key = os.environ["SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY"]

    desired_caps = {
        'platformName': os.environ["platformname"],  # os
        'platformVersion': os.environ["platformversion"],  # version
        'deviceName': os.environ["devicename"],  # device name
        'automationName': os.environ["automationname"],
        'appPackage': os.environ["apppackage"],
        'appActivity': os.environ["appactivity"],
        'app': os.environ["app"],
        'sauce:options': {  # Sauce custom capabilities
            "sessionCreationRetry": "2",
            "sessionCreationTimeout": "3000",
            "name": os.environ["jobname"] + time.strftime("%m-%d %H:%M")
        }
    }

    # launch app
    context.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://{}:{}@ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub".format(sauce_username, sauce_access_key), desired_caps)
    if context.driver is None:
        try:
            context.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://{}:{}@ondemand.saucelabs.com/wd/hub".format(sauce_username, sauce_access_key), desired_caps)
        except InvalidSessionIdException:
            return


    # add wait time
    context.driver.implicitly_wait(20)

    # app
    context.app = Application(context.driver)


def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.driver.save_screenshot("screenshot" + time.strftime("%y-%m-%d %H%M") + ".png")
    status = str(scenario.status)
    context.driver.execute_script('sauce:job-result='+status)
    context.driver.quit()
    if hasattr(context, 'driver') and context.driver is not None:
        try:
            if context.driver.session_id:
                context.driver.quit()
        except InvalidSessionIdException:
            return
    else:
        return True
```

I tried to look for answers here https://docs.saucelabs.com/dev/error-messages/index.html#test-didnt-see-a-new-command-for-90-seconds but we have `context.driver.quit()` already in the after_scenario. I'm thinking can we add context.driver.quit() too in before_scenario or do you guys have better suggestions?